# Mobile offline mapping and editing of shapefiles?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, software-recommendations, iphone

I've got a client that wants to create a mobile app that can view and edit shapefiles stored locally on the device to enable it to work offline. There is a possibility of converting the shapefiles to KML or other format if needed.

It would need to work on Android, iOS and Blackberry so a HTML5/Phonegap solution is preferred.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use a Mobile Web Service such as iJetty: http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/

and deploy a webGIS application such as [CartoWEB](http://cartoweb.org/) or similar.

Comment: Do you know any examples with the  implementation you describe above?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the HTML5 samples, Esri has an sample showing the offline/ local storage: [Tiles in Local Storage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/exp_webstorage.html). Should be possible to save as data as KML as well.

Answer (score -2):

There is an Android application: [SoM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dabebro.som&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kYWJlYnJvLnNvbSJd)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you post more details about SoM?